# .net core 6 swagger does not fetch controllerbase

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-6.0

I just created a fresh .net core api project with Swagger but it doesn't work with ControllerBase
i have configured swagger with or without addMvc and AddMvcCore etc... but still does not work

I need to use map.Get to see some methods in swagger....

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();


app.UseSwagger(options =>
{
    options.SerializeAsV2 = true;
});
//app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
    c.RoutePrefix = "";
});
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapSwagger();
//app.MapGet("api/Shipping/Ship/{id}", (Guid id) => {
//    return true;
//});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.Run();
```

This is my code :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace PrintApp.wwwroot.api
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET: api/<ValuesController>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/[controller]/Get/")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<ValuesController>/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<ValuesController>
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<ValuesController>/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<ValuesController>/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

by the way, i don't know why ControllerBase and ApiController attributes are not in green

Answer (score 1):

I have tested you code, it works well. So I beleive it's not code issue. You can follow my suggestions to fix this issue.

**Steps:**

1. Upgrade your VS2022 to latest version
2. Use the latest version of `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`, you can navigate to nuget to update it.
3. Delete `.vs`, `bin`, and `obj` folder.
4. Reboot your pc, and reopen the project by clicking `project_name.sln`.
5. check the issue, and it should be fixed.